# Visual Web Developer 2010 not opening database file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am learning ASP.NET by from book "Beginning ASP.NET 4 : in C# and VB".
here author instructed in database chapter to create a new ASP.NET Website project 
then in App_Data folder add a mdf file(this file comes with book source code). I did as instructed.

But when i double click the mdf it should open the database file in database explorer.But that's not happening it is giving me following error

[image]

Here is how solution explorer looks

[image]

What am i doing wrong ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place you App_Data Folder in root directory not in Account folder.Take it out from Account folder and place in root.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run visual studio in `administrator` mode. Add you `App_Data` folder at root level.